# Replacing local home server with VPS: Suggestions?

Tags: home-server, cloud

So right now, I'm running an old box with a 2TB HDD in it. I use this as a file server for the home network, as well as a box for downloading large files which are synced via Dropbox. Lots of other tinkering things, too.

Basically, I'm sick of paying extra for the power and having to worry about drive failures and whatnot. I'd rather get a remote server, let someone else manage it and provide access from the Internet.

So, I've been looking for a Windows VPS that would give me access to install things and tinker, and I'm having a problem finding a host that offers more than 100GB of hard drive space. If they do offer a package with 100GB of storage, everything else is waaayyyy more than what I actually need.

The idea is to create a permanent VPN connection from the cloud server to my home network to provide a transparent solution so I'm not having to go to lengths to transfer files or whatnot. I think a VPS solution will allow me to do this.

I would like 1TB of storage space, minimum 100Mbps Internet connection, minimum 250GB bandwidth, admin access.

Anyone have anything? Or am I being unreasonable? If I am, why?

Comment: Have you considered using [Amazon's S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/#pricing) service.  The vast majority of VPSes are setup to ensure data can be quickly moved around, and not for backup / bulk storage.  You might want to combine it with a smaller windows vps to tinker with, and ensure data is being backed up.   Also you might want to look into a "seed box", but again, I am not sure if that is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: I have seen S3, but the prices, even for non-redundant backup, are quite pricey for a TB. At $0.093/GB, a TB is still $93 a month :O

Answer (score 0):

You could get it, but quite frankly, for those specs, running your own seems cheaper. you could probably extend it with something like backblaze for backups

If you *have* to go cloud, you'd likely want to use something like [amazon s3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) or [rackspace cloud](http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/) for disk space, and mount the disks with something like [gladinet](http://www.gladinet.com/c/index.php/gladinet-products-services/) or jungledisk.

from random poking around numbers, it'll cost you something like 150-200 USD for what you want using that - which will cover the cost for a new fileserver in 2-3 months.

Comment: That's unfortunate... Any explanation as to why it is so expensive? It doesn't make sense how I can buy out hardware and power it for less than renting it. Wasn't the point of the cloud and server virtualization to make it more cost effective for these kinds of things, or is it so expensive for me simply due to markup?

Comment: well, its more cost effective than enterprise grade hardware and hosting, if you have very variable traffic needs or If you wanted to serve files out to lots of people, with very good, scalable performance, as opposed to backups. A single, home server + backblaze (for backups - at about 4 dollars a computer a month) will likely be a better idea for home users.